# What is the difference of Windows 8 Phone Application and Metro Style Application?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8

I will develop an application for Windows Phone 8. But i also want to make this application is usable on the other Windows 8 platforms. Wondering that, Does it work as a metro-style application? Or I will have to develope two different applications.

Answer (score 4):

The APIs are similar in some aspects (use of XAML, C#, common WinRT libraries), BUT there are some significant differences.

For instance:

1. The XAML/UI layer in Windows Phone is based on the Silverlight stack, and differs from that for Windows Store.
2. Not possible to write WinRT HTML5/JS app on phone (but it is possible to use WebBrowserControl to host HTML5 app especially with tools such as PhoneGap).
3. No C++/XAML development on phone (C++/DirectX is supported).
4. Phone has dedicated APIs in WinRT and .NET that aren't available on Windows Store.

Basically you'll have to produce two apps but you should be able to share large amounts of code between the two.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714089(v=vs.105).aspx for more details...

Comment: A full HTML5/JS app would be a browser application anyway. What you meant is a "WinRT application using HTML/JS for the UI code". Also, 3 is only for insane people, and obviously for 4, is that the phone have it's own APIs, it's a phone after all, you might consider the fact it can call people (though often forgot).

Comment: Thanks Claus - I'll amend 3.  4. is more than just phone calls - also things like `EmailComposeTask` which would make sense on a tablet but use Sharing.

Comment: @Claus I'd call 3. "niche". It's easier than MFC or raw Win32 and a few people seem to be getting caught out by it.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same type of application and use the same apis. A few changes may be needed but If you are looking for a general answer then yes, it will work as a metro app but will require modifications.

Comment: Can you sample these modifications? Also you mean, no need to different applications?

Comment: no, unfortunately this is coming to you second hand. I had a similar question and this was the response I received. Let me look around, though.

Comment: quick note though, this does not apply to JS apps. JS apps will only function in Win 8. If you want it on Windows Phone, use something like PhoneGap